# How to iterate over a list with key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can someone help me with this super newbie python problem. I tried googling multiple times.

**This is the list I have been provided:**

```py
fruits = [{"key":"Red","value":"Apple"},
 {"key":"Yellow-0","value":"Mango"},
{"key":"Green","value":"Banana"}]
```

**In some cases it could also be just:**

```py
fruits = [{"key":"Yellow-0","value":"Mango"}]
```

**Problem Statement**

I want to iterate over this list and match only when there's a `Yellow-0` or `Yellow-1` and so on until `Yellow-9`

**My code**

```py
import re

fruits = [{"key":"Red","value":"Apple"},
 {"key":"Yellow-0","value":"Mango"},
{"key":"Green","value":"Banana"}]

keyword = r"Yellow-\d"

for key in fruits:
    if keyword:
        print(fruits)
```

**My Output**:

```py
[{'key': 'Red', 'value': 'Apple'}, {'key': 'Yellow-0', 'value': 'Mango'}, {'key': 'Green', 'value': 'Banana'}]
[{'key': 'Red', 'value': 'Apple'}, {'key': 'Yellow-0', 'value': 'Mango'}, {'key': 'Green', 'value': 'Banana'}]
[{'key': 'Red', 'value': 'Apple'}, {'key': 'Yellow-0', 'value': 'Mango'}, {'key': 'Green', 'value': 'Banana'}]
```

**My Desired Output is to match Yellow-0 and return true as this will be part of a function**

```py
Yellow-0
```

Comment: `if keyword:` is always true, `keyword` is just a `str` object, the one you defined here: `keyword = r"Yellow-\d"`, non-empty strings always evaluate to true. You seem to expect this to work like a regex (hint: you even `import re` but you *never use it*)

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) put the answer in the question. If you have something that's more than just a recap of someone else's answer, you can post it as your own answer.

Comment: Apologies Noted and removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used regular expressions in Python, but this will probably work:

```
pattern = re.compile("Yellow-\d")
for fruit in fruits:
      if pattern.match(fruit['value']):
          print(fruit['value'])
```

And if it could be in 'key'...

```
pattern = re.compile("Yellow-\d")
for fruit in fruits:
      match = fruit['value'] if pattern.match(fruit['value']) else False
      match = fruit['key'] if not match and pattern.match(fruit['key']) else False
      if match:
          print(match)
```

And using the Ternary Operator `var = [value_1] if [condition] else [value_2]` keeps things organized so you dont have nested if/else statements to clutter the code.

Comment: Yay Thanks! this works. but you would have to edit this to `fruit['key']` and `print(fruit['key'])`

Comment: @V.I    I made an edit to account for it.

Answer (score 1):

why do you import re without using it?

You have a list of dictionaries:

```
for fruit in fruits:
      for key, value in fruit.items():
            if value ==  <your string>:
                  print(value)
```

Comment: What if `<your  string>` needs to be dynamic to account for a regex pattern. I tried to use it with the `r""` syntax but forgot to add `re.search""`

Comment: @Sterios This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You havn't implemented your list the right way, here is a simple solution without the need of importing some library.
hope it's helpful

```
#the name 'key' and 'value' are hundled by the dictionary brakets "{}" for that 
you do not need to write them

fruits = [{ "Apple": "Red"}, {"Mango": "Yellow-0"}, {"Banana": "Green"}]

#this is the string value you search for

DesiredString = "Yellow-0"

#Nested for loop to iterate over two stage [the fruit stage, and the key_value 
stage

for fruit in fruits :
    for key, value in fruit.items() :
        if value == DesiredString :
            print(key)
```